# Отследить событие по клику со своего сайта на ссылку в Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, события

Как настроить отсежевание события по клику на ссылку сайта в Google Analytics? http://joxi.ru/BA01vMGiBnn61r

Нашёл решение в интернете:
Надо подвязать событие onclick по этому примеру:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.example.com'); return false;">Открыть example.com</a>
```

В мою строку

```
<div class="coupon-code" cid="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-clipboard-text="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'coupon_code', true); ?>"  pop-info='<?php echo $pop_info; ?>' aff-url='<?php echo $coupon_aff_url; ?>'><?php echo $print_text; ?></div>
```

Как правильно вставить её, чтобы код отрабатывал корректно и при нажатии по ссылке на сайте был переход на страницу в отдельной вкладке

Answer (score 2):

Можно ведь просто добавить код в `onclick`

```
ga('send', 'event', 'event_category', 'event_action');
```

Comment: В какой именно код?

Comment: в php вставляй куда надо ссылку, а сама ссылка с отрытием в новом окне будет примерно такой: <a href="" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'event_category', 'event_action');" target="_blank">link</a>

Comment: вот я и не знаю как мне сюда в мой код <div class="coupon-code" cid="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-clipboard-text="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'coupon_code', true); ?>"  pop-info='<?php echo $pop_info; ?>' aff-url='<?php echo $coupon_aff_url; ?>'><?php echo $print_text; ?></div> такое поместить корректно. Можете вставить куда надо?